# Python 3.8 - UDP Receive doest'n work on second ethernet port (usb ethernet)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp

This code snippet works fine on my PC (Win10, Python 3.8), when I run it on the IP-address of my build-in ethernet card (192.168.0.122):

```
import socket

UDP_IP = '192.168.0.122'
#UDP_IP = '192.168.1.10'
UDP_PORT = 50001

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    print('running')
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("received message: %s" % data)'''
```

It works fine and prints out the data from my device sending the messages on IP 192.168.0.11.

If I change the IP-address of the script to my USB-ethernet adapter (192.168.1.10) and also change the IP of my transmitting device to a valid ip address (192.168.1.11), no data is shown.
They are connected correctly and I can see the udp-messages from the transmitter on my PC via Wireshark, but the Python script ignores them.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't bind to a specific IP address. Bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Neither UDP_IP = '0.0.0.0' nor UDP_IP = '' works.